# Python gTTS Speak Clipboard

Tags: python, clipboard

This used to work on my computer, but now I receive an error...AttributeError:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'.  Can someone explain why?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from gtts import gTTS
import os
import clipboard

try:
    mytext = clipboard.paste()
    language = 'en'
    myobj = gTTS(text=mytext, lang=language, slow=False)
    myobj.save("welcome.mp3")
    os.system("totem-audio-preview welcome.mp3")
    os.remove('welcome.mp3')
except IndexError:
    pass
finally:
    print("Finished")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an official fix now. It had to do with an upstream dependency of gtts, gtts-token. do pip uninstall gtts-token to remove existing gtts-token==1.1.1 and then again pip install gtts-token so that it will gtts-token==1.1.2
Thanks to open source gods and @carrey-cole

Comment: Did it and same result

Comment: try the following steps :                                                                                (1) pip freeze and  check gtts-token version. it should be 1.1.2                  (2)comment out the following lines of the code:  #os.system("totem-audio-preview welcome.mp3") and   # os.remove("welcome.mp3")                                (3)check if the welcome.mp3    is stored in directory.

Comment: The welcome.mp3 file is not being created, but the gtts-token version is at v.1.1.2.

Comment: @user192085 , in your code i cannot see **clipboard.copy** [see here for the syntax](https://pypi.org/project/clipboard/) . you can try  adding  the following line in try block ` clipboard.copy('hello i am fine') ' `mytext = clipboard.paste()'. also comment out  #os.system("totem-audio-preview welcome.mp3") and # os.remove("welcome.mp3"). now check if the welcome.mp3 is stored in directory. now at least the file should be saved.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by finding gtts-token from github, cloning it, and running python setup.py install.  Thanks to bipin_s for the contribution.